# Buzzing sound on Macbook Pro mid 2012 due to optical drive fixed?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, optical-drive

Am aware of the fact, there is a known problem as mentioned in this [Apple KB: Mac notebooks with optical drives: Noises from the optical drive](https://support.apple.com/HT201623) link, that is produced when the OS is initializing the optical drive. It seems to be occurring in OS X Yosemite for now, but would like to know if there is any possible fixes for it in the same OS version or upgrading it to OS X El Capitan will fix the problem.

Mine is the MBP 2012(mid-version), with 8 GB RAM and 500 GB SATA HDD. 
Any help regards to this appreciated!

Comment: How does it sound like? Like this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K0T60yZmiQw

Comment: Not this persistent sound! it doesn't last more than 2-3 seconds along with original apple chime!

Comment: Something like this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cIUVbq25uvY

Comment: Bingo! exactly the same! I could see it being no harmful in comments of the video! did a search myself, couldn't find then. Thanks a lot. If you could post that as answer, I will handover the bounty to you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The sound](http://youtube.com/watch?v=cIUVbq25uvY) is totally normal on older MacBook models and it's not a bug. It's from the optical drive looking for a boot up disk.